# How to call java method taking parameter as List<Class<?>> from Scala

Tags: java, scala, generics

I am trying to call a **java** method which takes `List<Class<?>>` from **scala**.

The compilation fails with

```
type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.List[Class[T]] where type T <: Person.type
 required: java.util.List[Class[_]]
```

I tried using JavaConverters but get the same error.

Java method:

```
void registerClasses(List<Class<?>> var1);
```

Calling from Scala:

```
def registerEntities() = registry.registerClasses(List(Person.getClass).asJava)
```

Comment: Not a solution, but what happens when you change the Java side to use a raw type, so just *List var1*)?

Comment: @GhostCat - Java side is a third party library. So, can't really change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the inferred type for `Person.getClass` is not the one you want. You need to specify the expected type, and this can be done by an explicit type parameter

```
registry.registerClasses(List[Class[_]](Person.getClass).asJava)
```

(I don't understand why type ascription doesn't work here:

```
registerClasses(List(Person.getClass: Class[_]).asJava)

type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.List[Class[_$2]] where type _$2
 required: java.util.List[Class[_]]
Note: Class[_$2] <: Class[_], but Java-defined trait List is invariant in type E.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Class[_]`. (SLS 3.2.10)
```

So far as I can tell it should.)

Comment: I can't get the type ascription to work, but it seems the type parameter works, so +1.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov - Thanks.  Type parameter works. However, it puzzles me why implicit conversion doesn't. IntelliJ doesn't complain but maven compilation fails.